# Changes in Web.config before publishing to online windows server

Tags: c#, asp.net

m new to asp.net and i am stuck badly, i have published the website and uploaded on server but when i browse it gives following errors in web.config file.

Error is in the line below

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="Login" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="NinjaBotMaster.login" %>
```

and here is my default.aspx file top lines

```
<%@ Page Title="Login" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="**********.login" %>

<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
```

Comment: Does the `Class` name in the `CodeBehind` file `Default.aspx.cs` match what the `Page` above `Inherits` from? You need to give more info on the error message...

Comment: Yes it matches perfectely

Comment: i am posting my web.config file here.. plz copy it to your notepad and see it

Comment: There isn't any `web.config` stuff in your post above. What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%@ Page Title="Login" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="**nameofmasterfile**" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="**name**" %>
```